# Makefile Link Error

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

So I recently upgraded by Linux Kernel to v3.8.8 and had to reinstall the drivers. Now the wifi driver installed and works properly now but the NTFS file reader module does not so I cant read and store data to my removable hard drive(DiskGo Edge). So I downloaded a package from tuxera.com( ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs.2014.2.5), extracted the files, used the ./configure command to configure the extracted files. Now I got a link error after using the command **make** and adding -fPIC to the compile command in the Makefiles (CFLAGS = -g -02 -fPIC) didn't work. Did I put the -fPIC flag in the wrong place? Note that using the command **./configure -fPIC** also produces the output:

```
DALEK ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2014.2.15 # ./configure -fPIC
configure: error: unrecognized option: `-fPIC'
Try `./configure --help' for more information
```

The link error message I get when I run the Makefile:

```
/usr/bin/ld: .libs/libntfs_3g_la-acls.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
.libs/libntfs_3g_la-acls.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libntfs-3g.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2014.2.15/libntfs-3g'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zermacr0yd/Downloads/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2014.2.15'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**UPDATE**:

Upon running the ./configure command and examining the config.log file I noticed that a number of header files are missing. This is in the autoconf generated source code file *conftest.c*. They are:

I googled these headers and they are not for the Linux Operating system. What is the Linux headers that have the UUID data structures?

Comment: Try `CFLAGS=-fPIC ./configure` ?

Comment: I did that and I got the SAME freakin error. So if you look at the edit you can see that there are some missing header files that are listed in the config.ac file: <uuid/uuid.h> and <minix/config.h>.